# Makefile: Match-Anything Pattern Rule

Tags: makefile

I have a main Makefile that calls Makefiles placed in subfolders. For testing purposes I would like to add Match-Anything rule at the end of main Makefile.
This rule would be:

```
%:
     make -e -C subdir $@
```

Are there any contrarguments for such a rule?

Comment: Depends on what a **cont** is.

Comment: cont is contrargument

Answer (score 1):

I think you meant "con", as in "pro or con", not "cont".  "Con" is short for the Latin "contra".

For your question, the downside of adding a new "match anything" rule is that any file that doesn't exist, will try to be created using this rule.  For example suppose you run `include foo.mk` and `foo.mk` doesn't exist... make will attempt to build `foo.mk` by running your rule.  Basically it can be confusing.  It's possible there could be some performance impact; if you run `make -d` and examine it you should see if your match-anything rule is being used at all during a normal build.  I'm not sure if there are any other serious downsides.

By the way you should always only use the make variable `$(MAKE)` when invoking a sub-make in a recipe; never use the raw `make` command.